# Displaying Eloquent data in two bootsrap colums (same row) Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade, has-many

I need some help with this blade template, it's for the homepage of a non-profit organisation, I have pulled all their categories on the homepage and i can drill down in the relationship to get the desired news but I have a issue in my loop or something, let me explain, I have one main block with two columns in each column I would like to display 4 news related to that category, but my loop reproduces on each column the same output, how do I get 2 columns with 8 news correctly formated, by that I mean no duplication of entries on output, thanks ahead.

[visual example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgPSs.png)

HomeController

`$categories = Category::with('latestNews')
                    ->orderBy('name', 'asc')
                    ->take(9)
                    ->get();`

Blade Template

```
<!-- block_inner -->
<div class="block_inner row">
    <!-- small_list_post -->
    <div class="small_list_post col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
        <ul>
         @foreach( $category->latestNews->take(8) as $news)         
            <li class="small_post clearfix">
            @if($news->Image_Thumb_Url)
                <div class="img_small_post">
                    <img src="{{$news->Image_Thumb_Url}}" alt="{{$news->title}}">
                </div>
            @endif
                <div class="small_post_content">
                    <div class="title_small_post">
                        <a href="#"><h5>{{ str_limit($news->title, 60, ' ...') }}</h5></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="post_date"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> <em><a href="#">{{$news->created_at->diffForHumans()}}</a></em></div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- // small_list_post -->

    <!-- small_list_post -->
    <div class="small_list_post col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
        <ul>
            <li class="small_post clearfix">
            @if($news->Image_Thumb_Url)
                <div class="img_small_post">
                    <img src="{{$news->Image_Thumb_Url}}" alt="{{$news->title}}">
                </div>
            @endif
                <div class="small_post_content">
                    <div class="title_small_post">
                        <a href="#"><h5>{{ str_limit($news->title, 60, ' ...') }}</h5></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="post_date"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i><em><a href="#"> {{$news->created_at->diffForHumans()}}</a></em></div>
                </div>
            </li>
        @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- // small_list_post -->
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't read the code but are you sure that in your DB there isn't two news that are alike?

Comment: Hi @Charlie, yes i'm postive about that it's outputting the same record twice but I think it's more of how I built my template insinde my loop and I'm also missing something, I'm reading about chunk() method I thinks that's what I have to use to display as per requirement. or maybe a condition like if it's the fourth item then put bootsrap column then finish the loop with the rest of the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you made an error in foreach statement which is breaking html code.

try this:

```
<!-- block_inner -->
    <div class="block_inner row">
    @foreach($category->latestNews->take(8)->chunk(4) as $newsChunk)
    <!-- small_list_post -->
    <div class="small_list_post col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
        <ul>
            @foreach($newsChunk as $news)
            <li class="small_post clearfix">
            @if($news->Image_Thumb_Url)
                <div class="img_small_post">
                    <img src="{{$news->Image_Thumb_Url}}" alt="{{$news->title}}">
                </div>
            @endif
                <div class="small_post_content">
                    <div class="title_small_post">
                        <a href="#"><h5>{{ str_limit($news->title, 60, ' ...') }}</h5></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="post_date"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> <em><a href="#">{{$news->created_at->diffForHumans()}}</a></em></div>
                </div>
            </li>
            @endofreach
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- // small_list_post -->
    @endforeach
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the markup fix @Rafael, it works like a charm ! I tried with take(2)->chunk(1) and got the expected result thank you so much this will be very usefull in the future !